# View exact query executed in ASP page

Tags: sql, asp-classic, command, ado

I've got stored procedures in my ASP code and I'd like to see the full command text (not just the (?,?,?,?) that will execute so I don't have to open up SQL Profiler.

Code is as follows:

```
sSQL="myProc"   
Set dbCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")    
Set dbCommand.ActiveConnection = oConn  
dbCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc 
dbCommand.Commandtext=sSQL  
dbCommand.Parameters.Append (dbCommand.CreateParameter("@tutorID", adInteger, adParamInput, 0, sTutorID))   
set oRST=dbCommand.Execute
```

Comment: Your command will be in the stored procedure. I don't think you can directly view it via ASP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading the value of `dbCommand.CommandText` after you set the parameter.

This should give you the full command that will be executed.  It won't give you the content of the stored procedure, though.